# inserting multiple mysql rows php Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-insert

Im trying to insert multiple mysql rows in an external database using a php script and Android. I pass a JSONObject to the PHP script from Android and Im trying to use this data to update multiple rows of a mysql database at once. The problem is in the PHP script

**PHP**

```
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$json = $_POST['json'];
$array = json_decode($json, true);


for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
     $name = $array['person'][0]['name'];
     $password = $array['person'][0]['password'];

     $sql = "insert into Test4Upload(name,password) values('$name','$password')";

    if(mysql_query($sql)){
    return 1; // Return 1 for success;
    }else{
    return 2;// Return 2 for database error;
}
}


?>
```

This is the JSONObject passed in
{"person":[{"age":0,"name":"Jim"},{"age":1,"name":"Harry"},{"age":2,"name":"bill"}]}

This only updates the database once rather than three times..Im wondering why this is so, and also If I change [0] to [i] then the database does not update at all?

Sorry Im used to coding in java so I have no idea why the loop iterations dont work the same,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$count=0;
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array['person'] as $item){
     $age= $item['age'];
     $name= $item['name'];
     $sql = "insert into Test4Upload(age,name) values('$age','$name')";
     if(mysql_query($sql))
     {
       $count++;
     }
}
return $count;
```

Comment: Invalid argument for foreach.. Actually I always seem to get this error whenever I run foreach loops

Comment: No it works fine, firstly check the code in my project

Comment: Solved this by casting $array['person']  to array.. And now it works.

Comment: Just one thing Sushant, If my @array is very large, with hundreds and potentially thousands of elements. Is there any way to make this more efficient by limiting the number of insert queries made?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is thas you call `return` after first loop:

```
 if(mysql_query($sql)){
    return 1; // Return 1 for success;
    }else{
    return 2;// Return 2 for database error;
```

and that `return` breaks your loop. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php